# JS: element.addEventListener to element created dynamically

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom-events

I'm having a little trouble adding an event listener to elements created dynamically.

I have a list of objects that represent matches a player plays in. And a for loop that iterates through them, creating 4 buttons for each match, a +1, a +2, a -1 and an END button.

However, even if they are well created, and appended where they should be, the event listeners are not kept. Here's a sample of my code:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";

    var plusOne = document.createElement("a");
    plusOne.id = "plusone_ " + matches[i].id;
    plusOne.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert('Clicked on plusOne!')
    });

    ...
    // adding plus two, minus one and END the same way
    // however, END does have an eventListener on click

    row.appendChild(plusOne);

    container.appendChild(row);

}
```

If anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Do you get any script errors?

Comment: Sure there isnt a different reason for the event not firing ? Like disabling pointing events in css and others ? I ran this code in the console (creating an empty div and a matches array) and it all went fine. Now that I click on the link the event fires ...

Comment: @astian yes i'm sure, I checked using getEventListeners ont the appended items..

Comment: @JoColina can you share your entire function ?

Comment: @astian http://pastebin.com/2tcwGCbv

Comment: I found the problem, apparently adding `container.innerHTML += "\n"` was what was preventing the DOM objects to be recognized